# org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory

Tags: kotlin, maven, gradle, build, build.gradle

I want to build a github project locally, and there is no POM file in the given repository.
Accroding to the README.md, i run "./gradlew installDependencies" in the terminal, and the console log is:

```
Successfully started process 'command 'mvn''
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.034 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-10-07T22:36:16+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/Users/Frontmatter/build/soot). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
:installSoot (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.824 secs.
Closing Git repo: /Users/Frontmatter/.git

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':installSoot'.
> Process 'command 'mvn'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

The instruction seems like i should cd /path/pomfile, but i am confused that there is just no pom file at all. So if i want to run this repository, should i create a new POM file by myself? Or is there any other solutions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the GitHub project?

Comment: Of course! Thank you for your reply! this is the link: https://github.com/uds-se/Frontmatter